# Guest Process with a reparented window hangs on Dialog invocation if Host process blocked on a WaitFor<...>

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I'm developing a multi-process framework for a complex application.
A Host process acts as a container, and one or more guest processes can be spawn from it.
A Window of such guest processes is reparented to a Hosts's window (such as a notebook tabSheet).
(InterProcess Communication is not an issue here - it works)
Imagine something similar to Google Chrome.
I've read many answers about reparenting windows across processes, but I can't figure out what's happening in this case:

- My Host (container) process happens to be doing a`WaitForMultipleObjects` on some Handles;
- A Guest Process invokes a `MessageBox`, but hangs.

Doesn't the guest process run on a separate message queue? What am I missing?

I think I followed the best guidelines about `SetParent` when I embedded the Guest Form:

```
SetWindowLong(GuestHWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(GuestHWND, GWL_STYLE) and WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY and (not WS_POPUP) or WS_CHILD);
SetParent(GuestHWnd, HostHWnd);
PostMessage(GuestHWnd, WM_UPDATEUISTATE, UIS_INITIALIZE, 0);
SendMessage(HostHWnd, WM_UPDATEUISTATE, UIS_INITIALIZE, 0);
SetWindowPos(GuestHWnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOZORDER or SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
```

Notice also that I haven't called any sort of `AttachThreadInput`.
The problem doesn't arise if the Host is not blocked, or if the Guest window is not a child of a host's (obviously).

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you to read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/31/10147981.aspx). I'm not sure it will solve your problem, but it can highlight some unconsidered details.

Comment: @mg30rg: please note that he uses "child/parent" and not "child/owner" relationship. Which in turn is explained in more recent post (see answer below)

Comment: Thank you. I see it is a dangerous solution, so I think I'll go for a detached solution.

Comment: @Daniel Didn't you link the exactly same article? - Nevermind. I was just trying to feel smart. :D

Comment: This sounds exactly like my question [Parent window freezes when child window freezes altough it's from another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817112/parent-window-freezes-when-child-window-freezes-altough-its-from-another-proces)

Comment: @Gunther: Yes, it is exactly where I found the same link Daniel suggests below :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only recommend Raymond chen's explanation to this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx

Long story short:

> Creating a cross-thread parent/child or owner/owned window
>   relationship implicitly attaches the input queues of the threads which
>   those windows belong to.

The problem is in this statement:

> Notice also that I haven't called any sort of AttachThreadInput. The
>   problem doesn't arise if the Host is not blocked, or if the Guest
>   window is not a child of a host's (obviously).

Since it's a child/parent relationship, there IS an implicit AttachThreadInput.

Comment: I think its more comment than answer material. (And I have already commented about it. :v)

Comment: Thank you. I was just reading the same page in the meantime :-)
I think I'll try a "detached" solution - No parent/child relationship